# Is there a PowerShell cmdlet to get the resources that reference a domain name in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Before deleting a custom domain from Azure Active Directory (AAD), I first need to get a list of all users, groups, and applications that reference that custom domain. This can be done manually through the Azure portal

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to get this list through PowerShell? I see the PowerShell cmdlet [Get-MsolDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoldomain?view=azureadps-1.0), but I do **not** see that this outputs this kind of information.

Comment: try the graph api, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use cmdlet **Get-AzureADDomainNameReference -Name ''** from module **AzureAD**.

You can install that module from PowerShell Gallery - **https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/**

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this from 3 years ago.  you can use
Get-MsolUser -DomainName DomainName.com | FL UserPrincipalName